# Error Can't resolve 'react-scroll' module in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-scroll' in
> 'D:\Projects\Temp Projects\my-app\src\components' assets by path
> static/ 31.8 MiB
>
> ERROR in ./src/components/ButtonElements.js 4:0-36 Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'react-scroll' in 'D:\Projects\Temp
> Projects\my-app\src\components'  @
> ./src/components/HeroSection/index.js 8:0-43 52:37-43  @
> ./src/pages/index.js 7:0-52 40:35-46  @ ./src/App.js 6:0-27 17:19-23
> 36:35-39  @ ./src/index.js 6:0-24 9:33-36

[image]

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import {Link} from 'react-scroll';


export const Button = styled.button`
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: ${({primary}) => (primary ? '#01BF71' : '#010606') };
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: ${({big}) => (big ? '14px 48px' : '12px 30px')};
    color: ${({dark}) => (dark ? '#010606' : '#fff')};
    font-size: ${({fontBig}) => (fontBig ? '20px' : '16px')};
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        background: ${({primary}) => (primary ? '#fff' : '#01BF71') };
    }


`;
```

> react-icons/fa

```
import React from "react";
import { FaFacebook, FaInstagram, FaYoutube, FaTwitter, FaLinkedin } from "react-icons/fa";
import { animateScroll as scroll } from "react-scroll/modules";

import { 
    FooterContainer,
    FooterWrap,
    FooterLinksContainer,
    FooterLinksWrapper,
    FooterLinksItems,
    FooterLinkTitle,
    FooterLink,
    SocialMedia,
    SocialMediaWrap,
    SocialLogo,
    WebsiteRights,
    SocialIcons,
    SocialIconLink,


} from "./FooterElements";
```

**

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './pages';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import SigninPage from './pages/signin';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';




function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      
      <Routes>
        <Route path= "/" component={Home} exact />
        <Route path= "/signin" component={SigninPage} exact />
      </Routes>
      <Home />
     
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install these packages with `yarn install` or `npm install`.
if these packages are not defined on the package.json file you must add this package or install it with npm or yarn for example: `npm install react-scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

React can't found the module react-scroll
So you have to install the module: `npm install react-scroll`
And also install the react-icons its also gives you error